# Find the drag coefficient $k$?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

A drag chute must be designed to reduce the speed of a 3000-lb dragster from 220 mph to 50 mph in 4 seconds. Assume that the drag force is proportional to velocity. What is the value of the drag coefficient $k$ needed to accomplish this?

I used this differential equation: $mv' = -mg - kv$

But since the dragster is going horizontally, $g = 0$, so

$mv' = -kv$

I went through the steps to simplify this and got $mln|v| = -kt + C$

At $v(0)$, $mln|v_{0}| = C$, so the equation becomes

$mln|v/v_{0}| = -kt$

$k = \frac{-mln|v/v_{0}|}{t}$

I'm fairly sure this is correct from looking around on other sites, but I'm uncertain about units. I don't think I can plug $3000$ into $m$ because it isn't a unit of mass. So would I use $F = ma$, with $F$ being $3000$ $lbs$ and $a$ being $62.334$ $ft/s^2$? I have no means of checking my answer, so I'm not sure if this is correct.

Answer (score 1):

The unit of mass in the English system is the slug.  The mass of the dragster is $3000/32 = 93.75$ slugs.  (Acceleration due to gravity in fps is 32 ft/s$^2$.  I'm not sure where you got the 62.334.)  Otherwise, you calculation is correct.